# how to check integer and string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

My list is `['1','2','to','3']`

I need to write a logic that

- convert '1' '2' which is string to 1, 2 which is integer
- print an error msg since 'to' string is included and cannot be converted to integer

Here's the code I have right now:

```
def average_file(filename):

    inputFile = open(filename, "r")
    inList = []
    results = []
    n = []

    for line in inputFile:
        inList.append(line.strip())  #inList.append(line)
        n = [int(elem) for elem in inList if elem.isdigit()] #I only remove the string and leave integer in my list, but I need a check logic to print error msg
        results = list(map(int, n))
    inputFile.close()

    results = sum(results)/len(results)
    return results
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is right now and how it ties in with your code. Why are you computing `results` every time a line is read? (It's not exactly wrong, but it's fishy.)

Comment: What do you want to do if you get non numbe? Do you want to throw an error and continue or break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

- The pythonic way to do it is to expect it to be an all digit value and handle the error when it is not.
- You can use `with` to handle your file lifetime.
- You can calculate sum and count of elements during the reading without saving additional array (and therefore know the average).
- `strip` is redundant when parsing to `int` like that `int(variable)`:

There you go:

```
def average_file(filename):

    summary = 0
    count = 0

    with open(filename, "r") as inputFile:
        for line in inputFile:
            try:
                summary += int(line)
                count += 1
            except ValueError as e:
                print('Can not parse "{0}" to a number'.format(line))

                # If reached here one of the values in the file is not a number and None is returned immediately
                return None

    # If count is 0 return None, otherwise return the average
    return (summary / count) if count else None
```

---

The answer was edited after some clarifications from OP:
Immediately return `None` when one of the values is not a number.

Comment: I input a test file (.txt) with string. I expect the error msg. However, it returned the float 51.22222222222222.          


the below is the content of my testing file


1
2
3
4
5
wut
6
7
8
9

Comment: @potentialwjy It makes no sense the average from my code came out `51.222` from input that the maximum value was `9`. Something else is wrong there. For the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'wut', 6, 7, 8, 9]` the result will be `5` and on the console you will see `Can not parse "wut" to a number`.

Comment: @potentialwjy Is **each** value on the file is in a new line?

Comment: my fault, I used the testing file in the class which is invisible..Now I use my testing file 1,2,3...wut...9, it shows:

Can not parse "wut
" to a number
Out[192]: 5.0

the expectation is to have the error msg only. It should not have the 5.0 as average in this case. Any thought? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @potentialwjy I edited my answer (added a `return None` at the `except` handler), have a look

Answer (score 2):

> convert '1' '2' which is string to 1, 2 which is integer print an
>   error msg since 'to' string is included and cannot be converted to
>   integer

```
source = ['1', '2', 'to', '3']
result = []

for item in source:
    try:
        result.append(int(item))
    except ValueError as ex:
        print('Not integer: {}'.format(item))

print(result)
```

Comment: Agree, just have written `ex` mechanically

Answer (score 1):

*Attempt* to convert each item to the list of results. If the conversion fails, print an error message.

```
l = ['1','2','to','3']

result = []
for item in l:
    try:
        result.append(int(item))
    except ValueError:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `try`/`except` block to separate the valid integer literals from everything else:

```
candidates = ['1','2','to','3']
for candidate in candidates:
    try:  # attempt the conversion
        value = int(candidate)
    except ValueError:  # conversion failed!
        print(candidate, 'is not an integer')
    else:  # conversion succeeded
        print(candidate, 'is the integer', value)
```

In your case, you can just collect the values in the `else` clause:

```
results = []
with open(filename) as input_file:
    for line in inputFile:
       try:
           value = int(line.strip())
       except ValueError:
           print(line.strip(), 'is not an integer')
       else:
           results.append(value)
```

Comment: your solution almost works...but my testing result shows:

wut is not an integer
5.0


my testing file is a txt with below info:
1
2
3
4
5
wut
6
7
8
9

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['1', '2', 'word', '4']
```

You can do:

```
n = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else print('\nNot able to convert: '+i) for i in l]
```

Output:

```
Not able to convert: word
l = [1, 2, None, 4]
```

Comment: Wouldn't that add `None` elements to `n`...  Edit: I'm getting a syntax error for `else print`.

Comment: I don't think `print` statements are suitable for list comprehensions.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I should have tried it, I'll modify it